# Extract array elements from JSON array with Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON data like bellow

```
[{"Staffs":[5,10,12,14]},{"Staffs":[11,13,15,17]}]
```

and I want to extract value from it and expect bellow data

```
[5,10,12,14,11,13,15,17]
```

How can I do this with newtonsoft JSON .

Comment: You first need to translate this json to an array of objects with Staffs property. Then use linq to merge those property values in to a single array.

Comment: Use http://json2csharp.com/ to create C# classes for your json.

Comment: Hi @ChetanRanpariya Thanks for reply,can you please give me some code example with newtonsoft json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first parse the JSON to a `JArray`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var array = JArray.Parse(yourJSONString);
```

Then, use `SelectMany` to flatten it and convert it to a `List<int>`:

```
var result = array.SelectMany(x => x["Staffs"]).Values<int>().ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @Sweeper thanks for your reply I have another json [{"Manager":6},{"Manager":8}] and I want only value as an array ,like [6,8] and apply your code but not working.can you please help ?

Comment: @kuntal If the inner values are not arrays, you'd have to use `Select` instead.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a model

```
class StaffsModel
{
    [JsonProperty("Staffs")]
    public int[] Staffs { get; set; }
}
```

if we consider to created a json value by object like this

```
var staffsList = new List<StaffsModel>();
staffsList.Add(new StaffsModel { Staffs = new[] { 5, 10, 12, 14 } });
staffsList.Add(new StaffsModel { Staffs = new[] { 11, 13, 15, 17 } });
```

we can serialize to array with this method

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(staffsList);
```

with this output `[{"Staffs":[5,10,12,14]},{"Staffs":[11,13,15,17]}]`

and finally added to list of numbers

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StaffsModel[]>(json);
if (data?.Length > 0)
{
    var listOfNumbers = new List<int>();
    foreach (var staff in data)
    {
        foreach (var number in staff.Staffs)
        {
             listOfNumbers.Add(number);
        }
    }
}
```